# C# WPF Crash in the constructor during the initialization of a TextBox element?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, listview

I've the class Person:

```
public class Person {

public Person(string nome) {
        this.Name.Text = nome;
        this.Name.Background = Brushes.Red;
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Name.Text.ToString()); 
    }
    public TextBox Name;
}
```

In the main, I've

```
List<Person> items = new List<Person>();
Person p = new Person("Samantha");
items.Add(p);
listView.ItemsSource = items;
```

Now, in the xaml file, i've a GridView which contain the listView. All is ok if instead TextBox Name I put string Name. But I need the background color, so I used a TextBox.

The problem is that the constructor Person crash in "this.Name.Text = nome;" and I don't understand why. Thanks to all

Comment: You aren't initializing the TextBox so you are getting a null reference exception when trying to set the text value. This isn't how you should do this anyways though.

Comment: @LeeO. thanks, I forgot... Can I ask you also another thing, please? 
In the xaml I've: 
<GridViewColumn Width ="150" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>

If name was a string, it was show. But it cannot see anything if I've a TextBox..

Comment: I'm assuming the ItemsSource of the ListView is binding to a List<Person> so the DataContext of each row of the GridView is a Person. You would want to bind to the Name.Text value. Please don't do this though. Get rid of the TextBox and properly use a string for that Property. Ask a new question to figure out how to set the color.

Comment: Your class has way too many responsibilities - it shouldn't be responsible for its own representation, also this is kind of coupling between `Person` and `TextBox` (or the framework behind). Your `Person` objects could not live alone without the framework being able to represent them.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the suggestion:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have declared a TextBox called Name (what a bad name!, change it) and you have not created it!
You need to create a new instance of TextBox before you can use it.

Then we can discuss why you are putting a TextBox in your class ;-)